# Transparent Gradient Reflection - VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, alpha

I'd like to know how to go about adding an upside down gradient reflection, similar to this:

[image: iPhone Reflection]

I would theorize first reflecting a bitmap to be upside down. Then, in Photoshop, I would add an alpha mask to the image, with a top to bottom black/white gradient.

How do I add the alpha mask/gradient combo in VB.NET? I can't seem to find any function to do so.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this with a gradient?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `Bitmaps`

```
Dim bm_src1 As Bitmap = CType(pb1.Image.Clone, Bitmap)
Dim bm_out As New Bitmap(bm_src1.Width, bm_src1.Height)
Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm_out)
  'Flip image
  gr.TranslateTransform(CSng(bm_src1.Width / 2), CSng(bm_src1.Height / 2))
  gr.RotateTransform(180)
  gr.TranslateTransform(-CSng(bm_src1.Width / 2), -CSng(bm_src1.Height / 2))
  ' Give the images alpha gradients.
  Dim alpha As Integer
  For x As Integer = 0 To bm_src1.Width - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To bm_src1.Height - 1
      alpha = (255 * y) \ bm_src1.Height
      Dim clr As Color = bm_src1.GetPixel(x, y)
      clr = Color.FromArgb(alpha, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B)
      bm_src1.SetPixel(x, y, clr)
    Next
  Next
  ' Draw the images onto the result.
  gr.DrawImage(bm_src1, 0, 0)
End Using
' Display the result.
pbResult.Image = bm_out 'picturebox output
```

Comment: When I view this image in a PictureBox, it has a black background. Is there any way to fix that?
Also, how can I make it spawn the new reflected bitmap as only 1/3 the height of the original, so it reflects the bottom third of the src?

Comment: Nevermind on the second half of that question.
Is there any way to improve performance? Per-pixel drawing is incredibly slow for large bitmaps.

Comment: Make the images ahead of time then just display them if you don't need them dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need them dynamically. How can I go about fixing the black background issue?

Comment: Happens with any source image with PixelFormat32bppArgb.

Comment: I know the issue is PixelFormat32bppArgb because when I pass a colored PixelFormat32bppRgb bitmap to it, it works perfectly. Still not sure what's going on. It's an issue with the alpha channel but I don't know why that would be an issue. Any ideas?...